# Making autoXrefs to figure captions in Word 2007?

Tags: vba, ms-word

The following code, from "Word Hacks: Tips & Tools for Taming Your Text", automatically cross-references the selected text to any heading with identical content. I've been trying to tweak it in order to automatically cross-reference a figure caption with identical content, with no success. The idea is that if the user selects "Figure 3-5" in any line of text (such as in a paragraph that says "For more info, see Figure 3-5"), the code should look for the corresponding figure caption and automatically insert a cross-reference to it.

```
Sub MakeAutoXRef() 
    Dim sel As Selection 
    Dim rng As range 
    Dim para As Paragraph 
    Dim doc As Document 
    Dim sBookmarkName As String 
    Dim sSelectionText As String 
    Dim lSelectedParaIndex As Long 
    Set sel = Selection 
    Set doc = sel.Document 
    If sel.range.Paragraphs.Count <> 1 Then Exit Sub 
    lSelectedParaIndex = GetParagraphIndex(sel.range.Paragraphs.First) 
    sel.MoveStartWhile cset:=(Chr$(32) & Chr$(13)), Count:=sel.Characters.Count 
    sel.MoveEndWhile cset:=(Chr$(32) & Chr$(13)), Count:=-sel.Characters.Count 
    sSelectionText = sel.text 
    For Each para In doc.Paragraphs 
        Set rng = para.range 
        rng.MoveStartWhile cset:=(Chr$(32) & Chr$(13)), _ 
        Count:=rng.Characters.Count 
        rng.MoveEndWhile cset:=(Chr$(32) & Chr$(13)), _ 
        Count:=-rng.Characters.Count 
        If rng.text = sSelectionText Then 
            If Not GetParagraphIndex(para) = lSelectedParaIndex Then 
                sBookmarkName = GetOrSetXRefBookmark(para) 
                If Len(sBookmarkName) = 0 Then 
                    MsgBox "Couldn't get or set bookmark" 
                    Exit Sub 
                End If 
                sel.InsertCrossReference _ 
                referencekind:=wdContentText, _ 
                referenceItem:=doc.Bookmarks(sBookmarkName), _ 
                referencetype:=wdRefTypeBookmark, _ 
                insertashyperlink:=True 
                Exit Sub 
            Else 
                MsgBox "Can't self reference!" 
            End If 
        End If 
    Next para 
End Sub 


Function RemoveInvalidBookmarkCharsFromString(ByVal str As String) As String 
    Dim i As Integer 
    For i = 33 To 255 
        Select Case i 
        Case 33 To 47, 58 To 64, 91 To 96, 123 To 255 
            str = Replace(str, Chr(i), vbNullString) 
        End Select 
    Next i 
    RemoveInvalidBookmarkCharsFromString = str 
End Function


Function ConvertStringRefBookmarkName(ByVal str As String) As String 
    str = RemoveInvalidBookmarkCharsFromString(str) 
    str = Replace(str, Chr$(32), "_") 
    str = "_" & str 
    str = "XREF" & CStr(Int(90000 * Rnd + 10000)) & str 
    ConvertStringRefBookmarkName = str 
End Function 


Function GetParagraphIndex(para As Paragraph) As Long 
    GetParagraphIndex = _ 
    para.range.Document.range(0, para.range.End).Paragraphs.Count 
End Function 


Function GetOrSetXRefBookmark(para As Paragraph) As String 
    Dim i As Integer 
    Dim rng As range 
    Dim sBookmarkName As String 
    If para.range.Bookmarks.Count <> 0 Then 
        For i = 1 To para.range.Bookmarks.Count 
            If InStr(1, para.range.Bookmarks(i).name, "XREF") Then 
                GetOrSetXRefBookmark = para.range.Bookmarks(i).name 
                Exit Function 
            End If 
        Next i 
    End If 
    Set rng = para.range 
    rng.MoveEnd unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=-1 
    sBookmarkName = ConvertStringRefBookmarkName(rng.text) 
    para.range.Document.Bookmarks.Add _ 
    name:=sBookmarkName, _ 
    range:=rng 
    GetOrSetXRefBookmark = sBookmarkName 
End Function
```

Comment: could you please show us that post which you refer to in the question? could be useful instead of searching... it's enough if you link it in comment here

Comment: Here it is, KazJaw. Thank you for your help! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15042741/vba-word-auto-cross-referencing-figures

Comment: by the way, does it work for you? macro tries to set crossreference to itself according to my quick test. as long as `sel` is `selection` calling `sel.InsertCrossReference` result with the error in the application. please check and/or comment...

Comment: Hi KazJaw. It does not work for me. When I run it, seems to do something quickly in the bgd, but does not add any crossreferences. It doesn't show any error messages either.

Comment: Say you have a very long user guide with a few hundred pictures with their corresponding captions. Every time there is a reference in the text to a figure, for example "For more information, see Figure 3.1", I want to be able to select "Figure 3.1" in the text (not in the caption), run the macro, and convert the selected text to a crossreference to the actual caption of Figure 3.1.

Answer (score 0):

So, I hope I get your point. To be honest it's a bit complicated to use `insertCrossReference` method as it has one disadvantage- when is set it places into the selected range whole 'name' of the title you catching references to. In other words: if your title is 'Figure 1.2. January sales results' and you want 'Figure 1.2' to link with title it would replace your 'Figure 1.2' into the long original title. Therefore, the base idea which you presented keep paragraph references.
However, I've made some trials and propose the followings: a) instead of `MakeAutoXRef` subroutine put the following code into Module:

```
Sub findToReference()

Dim whatTo As Range
Set whatTo = Selection.Range

Dim whatToTxt As String
    whatToTxt = whatTo.text
Dim sBookmarkName As String

Dim rngDoc As Range
Set rngDoc = ActiveDocument.Content

With rngDoc.find
    .text = whatTo
    .Style = "Headings 1"   'place name of style here, like 'Headings 1' or something
    .Execute
End With

If rngDoc.find.Found = True Then
    'rngDoc.Select     'selection what was fount
    'found text to bookmark
    sBookmarkName = GetOrSetXRefBookmark(rngDoc)
    'copy from previous
     If Len(sBookmarkName) = 0 Then
                MsgBox "Couldn't get or set bookmark"
                Exit Sub
    End If

    whatTo.InsertCrossReference _
                referencetype:=wdRefTypeBookmark, _
                referencekind:=wdContentText, _
                referenceItem:=rngDoc.Bookmarks(sBookmarkName), _
                insertashyperlink:=True
 Else
    MsgBox "No headers matching selection found!"

End If
End Sub
```

Some comments: I propose to use `find` feature which looks for both text you selected and checks if the style name refers to headings. Therefore you have to change `Headings 1` into appropriate style name. The other point is that 1st occurrence will match and set the reference to text you selected.

Additionally you need to change one function. Replace original `GetOrSetXRefBookmark` function with the one below.

```
Function GetOrSetXRefBookmark(paraRng As Range) As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim rng As Range
Dim sBookmarkName As String
   sBookmarkName = ConvertStringRefBookmarkName(paraRng.text)
   paraRng.Bookmarks.Add _
      Name:=sBookmarkName, _
      Range:=paraRng
GetOrSetXRefBookmark = sBookmarkName
End Function
```

It works fine for me with Word 2010. One disadvantage of presented idea is the situation, that each `crossreference` creates new bookmark. But it was my only idea to get rid of 'paragraph matching and full name copying' from original code.
So, I hope you get my point and that would be helpful.

Comment: Hi KazJaw, thank you VERY MUCH for this huge effort. Now I'm leaving the office. I'll test it during the weekend and come back to you as soon as I know how it works. Highly appreciated!

Comment: Hi KazJaw. I followed your instructions and tested your code. It gives an error "Bad bookmark name" which points to the line "paraRng.Bookmarks.Add _ ..." in the GetOrSetXRefBookmark function. Don't understand the problem. Thanks!

Comment: In case it helps: I wrote "Figure 3-1" somewhere in the text. Then I selected it and run your sub, hoping that it would make a cross-reference to the actual "Figure 3-1" caption. It gives me the aforementioned error. When I hover the mouse over the "paraRng.Bookmarks.Add _ ..." line, it shows ' sBookmarkName = "XREF73499_Figure_31" ' Don't know if this is important, but all figure and table captions use the current chapter number and the figure number separated by a hyphen, like so: "Figure 3-1" (Chapter 3, first figure in this chapter).

Comment: Please raise that error once again and hoover mouse over the `paraRng` in the error line and give me please the info you would see.

Comment: Moreover, please check all bookmarks in your document- how many bookmarks you have?? if there is too much of them and you don't need them try to delete all which you don't need. Then run macro again.

Comment: Hi KazJaw. I don't have many bookmarks (8 or 9, but there could be many more in the future. Hope the macro's success does not depend on this). I run the macro again. It says paraRng = "Figure 31", without the hyphen between the two numbers.

Comment: I launched Word 2007 to check what's going on (as the code was prepared and tested in 2010). I got your error twice- first time was before I deleted all existing bookmarks (so, please do so is possible or delete all which name includes `figure 31`). The second time I had an error when I didn't select range 'Figure 3-1' which I though I do. No another problem situation. So, please check this comment and...I hope it would work!

Comment: Hi KazJaw. I rebooted the computer, opened my document in Word and tried it again. Now it shows no errors. But it doesn't convert the selected range (Figure 3-1) into a crossreference. It does not seem to do anything. :( If I try to debug step by step with F8, when it reaches "If rngDoc.Find.Found = True Then" it shows "False", then moves to End If and End Sub and starts all over again. Does not call any function. :( Any idea what could be causing this behavior? Oh, and I deleted ALL bookmarks first.

Comment: I improved code by adding `Else MsgBox "No headers matching selection found!"` which show message if no referencing title is found. As I trace your comments I think that general everything is ok. Errors reported earlier proved you had heading title set correctly (which didn't possibly happened after rebooting). If you have: a) selected pain text, b) set headings with appropriate style with selected text within it, c) no bookmars, d) run macro `findToReference`... than it should work...

Comment: Hi KazJaw. Sorry but I don't understand what you mean in b). I have ".Style = "Caption" (that is the style name of the target) in the code. I select plain text (Normal) style and run the macro. But the macro interprets "If rngDoc.Find.Found = True" as false and I don't know why. So just to make sure I understand you correctly: I select plain text "Figure 3-1" (Normal syle) expecting to convert the selection into a crossreference to the "Figure 3-1" in the Caption (which has the Caption style applied to it). The taerget is not a heading. It is a caption with the "Caption" style.

Comment: you select "Figure 3-1" (Normal style) which search in the whole document any other "Figure 3-1" text with Caption style. If found `rngDoc.Find.Found` return true. After rebooting it doesn't find that caption (I think). The caption style name must be in the code instead of "Heading 1"

Comment: Yes, as I said before, I have ".Style = "Caption" in the code, and in the document I have "Figure 3-1" in Normal text and "Figure 3-1" with Caption style. I select the "Figure 3-1" Normal and run the macro. It does not convert it to a cross-reference to "Figure 3-1" in Caption style. And I have deleted ALL bookmarks.

Comment: This is what I have in the code:  .Style = "Caption"   'place name of style here, like 'Headings 1' or something

Comment: I think I can't help you any more as the solution I provided works quite fine. What I could suggest is to run macro carefully with key F8 (press one time pre line in VBA editor) instead of F5. If you encounter `.Style =` line, `if's` lines and other important points please analyse if there is any logic in the compilation behaviour. If you have any doubts please try to change, analyse, manipulate. And so on... And please report final solution if found.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, KazJaw. I have tried running it with F8 (as I explained before), but it drops out in the "If rngDoc.Find.Found = True Then" line. For some reason that I don't understand, it wrongly considers it False. I will keep trying. I know I'm close to it. Thank you very much again!!!

Comment: `If rngDoc.Find.Found = True Then` means that it didn't find text which meet both requirements: equals to text currently selected and with appropriate style named 'Heading 1` in my original code. You changed that style name into (I guess) Caption which could be wrong. Possibly you should place 'Caption 1'. Try exactly the name you see in 1st tab in Word Application.

Comment: Well, you say in your code I should replace "Heading 1" with the real name of the style used in the caption. And the real style is called "Caption", not "Caption 1". But, strangely enough, if I create a Heading 4 with the following text: "Figure 3-1 More words", and I change the line in the code to "Heading 4" it works perfectly. So why is it not able to do the same with a "Figure 3-1" in Caption style?

Comment: Check if that style has the same name in application and in VBA. Select any Caption's style text in document and run this line in VBA editor's immediate window: `? selection.Style`.

Comment: I checked in the immediate window. It is exactly the same: "Caption". Does the fact that the two numbers in the caption are fields has something to do? Or not at all?

Comment: Where did you place the `Else MsgBox "No headers matching selection found!"` line? And what if I wanted to apply a specific style to the "Figure 3-1" in plain text after converting it to a cross-reference (once I manage to make it work)? Thanks!!!

Comment: Check `MsgBox` in answer code which I updated 3 hour ago. For the other question I suggest to try. Your problem seems to be a kind tricky therefore best option is just to try.

Comment: No, I mean where in the code should I insert `Else MsgBox "No headers matching selection found!"`? Thanks!

Comment: Oh, ok. Now I understood. Did not understand that you had updated the code in this site. Sorry! KazJaw... Please look at this line: `'rngDoc.Select     'selection what was fount`. Did you really want to comment out the whole line?

Comment: you could uncomment it if you want to trace 'visually' what was found, only for test with F8 debugging.

Comment: Ok... so I run the edited code and it shows the "No headers matching selection" message box. Mmmmm. If I hover over `If rngDoc.Find.Found = True ` it shows me `True = True`, but then it jumps to `Else MsgBox `. Very strange.